# deploy office 2010 addin in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vsto, add-in, office-2010

I developed an Excel addin 2007 in Visual Studio 2008.Now i Need to Deploy the addin to Office 2010.Can i Do it in Visual Studio 2008?

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

Interop or VSTO ?

for VSTO is possible with VS 2008 and.NET 3.5
look at this picture http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jensha/archive/2010/04/28/vsto-versionen-erkl-rt.aspx

for Interop change references to office 14, excel 14 and clean/recompile